# GoogleAPIclient NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, google-api

I am running trying to get user current location in AsyncTask and transfer Location object as return value back to calling activity(Which contains Latitude,Longitude etc).

But whenever i call Asynctask from my activity like this

```
new AsyncTask_GetLocation(Navigation_Drawer.this,location_interface,1,1,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).execute();
```

Above line will start AsyncTask for getting location.

```
public class AsyncTask_GetLocation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Location> implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    Context context;
    GoogleApiClient LocationapiClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location_Interface locationInterface;
    int Interval;
    int Fastest;
    int Priority;

    public static final String TAG="###GET LOCATION###";

    public AsyncTask_GetLocation(Context context,Location_Interface location_interface, int interval, int fastest, int priority) {
        this.context = context;
        Interval = interval;
        Fastest = fastest;
        Priority = priority;
        locationInterface=location_interface;
    }

    @Override
    protected Location doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Do in Background Running "+context);
        GoogleAPI(context);
        LocationapiClient.connect();
        if (mCurrentLocation!=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Current Location Is Not Null "+mCurrentLocation);
            return mCurrentLocation;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Location location) {
        super.onPostExecute(location);
        locationInterface.userCurrent_Location(location);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(LocationapiClient,this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ON CONNECTED CALLED GOOGLE API CONNECTED ");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(LocationapiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG,"On Location Changed");
        mCurrentLocation=location;
    }
    private void requestLocationUpdate(int Interval,int Fastest,int Priority) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Request Location Update Calling");
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(Interval);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(Fastest);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(Priority);
    }

    public synchronized void GoogleAPI(Context apiContext){
        requestLocationUpdate(Interval,Fastest,Priority);
        Log.d(TAG,"Location Api Client Value "+LocationapiClient);
        if (LocationapiClient==null){
            LocationapiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(apiContext) // THIS LINE THROW NPE  
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }

        LocationapiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

LogCat

```
04-26 18:33:18.325 15252-15725/com.example.com.Loc D/###GET LOCATION###: Location Api Client Value null
04-26 18:33:18.325 15252-15725/com.example.com.Loc W/dalvikvm: threadid=21: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d53378)
04-26 18:33:18.425 15252-15725/com.example.com.Loc E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.getMainLooper(ContextWrapper.java:96)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.example.com.Loc.Location_system.AsyncTask_GetLocation.GoogleAPI(AsyncTask_GetLocation.java:102)
                                                                                      at com.example.com.Loc.Location_system.AsyncTask_GetLocation.doInBackground(AsyncTask_GetLocation.java:48)
                                                                                      at com.example.com.Loc.Location_system.AsyncTask_GetLocation.doInBackground(AsyncTask_GetLocation.java:24)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
04-26 18:33:18.695 15252-15334/com.example.com.Loc I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
04-26 18:33:18.785 15252-15334/com.example.com.Loc D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, timestamp=1493211798437, fatal=1}]
04-26 18:33:18.935 15252-15334/com.example.com.Loc D/FA: Connected to remote service
04-26 18:33:19.335 15252-15725/com.example.com.Loc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at android.content.ContextWrapper.getMainLooper(ContextWrapper.java:96)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.example.com.Loc.Location_system.AsyncTask_GetLocation.GoogleAPI(AsyncTask_GetLocation.java:102)
                                                                                   at com.example.com.Loc.Location_system.AsyncTask_GetLocation.doInBackground(AsyncTask_GetLocation.java:48)
                                                                                   at com.example.com.Loc.Location_system.AsyncTask_GetLocation.doInBackground(AsyncTask_GetLocation.java:24)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
04-26 18:33:19.525 15252-15252/com.example.com.Loc D/###Navigation Drawer###: ON PAUSE CALLING
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the `logcat' that the method trying to call:

```
getMainLooper()
```

And this is a call to get access to the main thread, and since you call it in the background thread of the `AsyncTask`, it throw the erroe.

I suggest that you will move the initializing call for the `GoogleApiClient` to the main thread, either by put the code in the life cycle of the `Activity`, or by using the `onPreExecute` method that `AsyncTask` supply you just for this kind of things, when you need to have access to the main thread before start the work you want to do in the background:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        GoogleAPI(context);
    }
```

Comment: I tried your way but it gives me same error.Even i checked context value before executing `GoogleAPI(context);` which is not null. I moved my `        GoogleAPI(context);` to `onPreExecute` which gives me same error and also in log i can also see `at android.content.ContextWrapper.getMainLooper(ContextWrapper.java:96)`

Comment: What is `Navigation_Drawer.this`?

Comment: I'm almost sure that the `Context` you handed to the `AsyncTask` is not good, it's need to be `Activity` context. I run your code in my project with small changes and it worked.

Comment: `Navigation_Drawer.this` is class which extends `Activity`. I am calling from inner class that's why its not taking `this` as context.

Comment: For some reason the handed `Context` is instance `ContextWrapper`. I looked at the source code and the exact call is: ` return mBase.getMainLooper();` , so the problem is that the base `Context` is not valid anymore where the code is execution. try to use `Navigation_Drawer.this.getApplicationContext()` instead.

Comment: sorry for the late reply i will test and get back to you.Thanks for your support :)

Comment: Now NPE error throwing at `new AsyncTask_GetLocation(Navigation_Drawer.this.getApplicationContext(),location_interface,1,1,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).execute();` and the error logcat is showing. `                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)`

Comment: Can you put the code of your inner class in the question? Obviously, `Navigation_Drawer.this` is not valid context when you call it.

Comment: Ok.I think you right so that means i need to change my whole code cuz of this will you help me ?

Comment: Here is our team gist on which i am working on. where i want to fetch user location which should be in AsyncTask and get result back into particular block of code.
https://gist.github.com/varun7952/eec2c8a8d97f7c2d40960c2367ae3fa6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142874/discussion-between-yshahak-and-ritu).